# Android Studio Emulator : process exit with error code 1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I installed Android studio on My windows 7 64 bit Ultimate sp-1. When i run my nexus 5 api 27 emulator then it shows

```
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Isn`t here anybody who can please help me........ :-(

Comment: You should be using at least **Windows 8.1** for the Android SDK and emulators, anything older will sooner or later stop working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason: Incorrect exit or shutting down of emulator.
Simplest solution: Clone the same device emulator. So open the virtual emulator settings and clone the same emulator and repeat the setting up process.

Comment: I am now downloading oreo for 64 and 86 bit.. I tell after i try using it

Answer (score -1):

**[Problems]**

If you get  error "Android Studio Emulator: process exit with error code 1"

OR

Your play button of the emulator is not working, Then follow the below mention steps

**[SOLUTION]**

**Step 1: Restart your system and Press F10**

**Step 2: You will be landed on the BOIS Setting page as shown below**

[image: Step 1: Restart your system and Press F10]

**Step 3: Go to Advanced**

[image]

**Step 4: Go to System Options, You will be landed on the blow screen**

Select: Virtualization Technology (VTx) and Virtualization Technology for Directed I/0(VTd) and Click on Save

[image]

**Step 5: Click on Save  Exit from BOIS Setting  Restart System and Then Try**

[image]